# Listing installed QGIS plugins via PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Can you please tell me how I can programmatically (or from the console) access the loaded plugin list? I tried:

```
QgsProviderRegistry.pluginList()
```

but got:

> TypeError: QgsProviderRegistry.pluginList(bool asHtml=False): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QgsProviderRegistry

I am sure I am missing something, but don't know what. How can I get access to the actual `QgsProviderRegistry` instance?

Answer (score 14):

Actually, you would need to access the *instance* method of the QgsProviderRegistry class, since it is a singleton:

```
QgsProviderRegistry.instance().pluginList()
```

However, as you can see, it doesn't list QGIS plugins, but data provider plugins, which are used by QGIS to support different data formats such as WFS, PostgreSQL/PostGIS, WMS, GDAL, etc.

To achieve what you're looking for, type in the QGIS Python console:

```
qgis.utils.available_plugins
```

You could even access the list of active plugins (i.e., those plugins loaded by QGIS and not unchecked by the user):

```
qgis.utils.active_plugins
```