# Algorithm fails (not found) : gdalogr:warpreproject

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am using the code in "QGIS Python Programming Cookbook", testing the code to learn about programming in QGIS. But when I try to reproject a raster, I get the error: *Error: Wrong number of parameters*. When I type in *processing.alghelp("gdalogr:warpreproject")* it returns "Algorithm not found".  Here is my code:

```
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

Processing.initialize()
Processing.updateAlgsList()
#load a raster layer and set a COORDINATE SYSTEM
rasterLyr = QgsRasterLayer("G:\...\INPUT.ecw","MTN50")
print rasterLyr.isValid()
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(25830, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
rasterLyr.setCrs(crs)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([rasterLyr])
#now, REPROJECT
processing.runalg("gdalogr:warpreproject", rasterLyr, "EPSG:25830", "EPSG:3722", None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, "\0, C:\..\output.ecw")
```

I am using QGIS Essen, 2.14. Is it a problem of using a code that isn't updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed your [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171539/has-the-warp-reproject-tool-changed-in-qgis-2-12/171674?noredirect=1#comment286623_171674) on a previous post just now. You need use `warpreproject`, not `warpproject`.

```
import processing
processing.alghelp("gdalogr:warpreproject")

ALGORITHM: Warp (reproject)
    INPUT <ParameterRaster>
    SOURCE_SRS <ParameterCrs>
    DEST_SRS <ParameterCrs>
    NO_DATA <ParameterString>
    TR <ParameterNumber>
    METHOD <ParameterSelection>
    RTYPE <ParameterSelection>
    COMPRESS <ParameterSelection>
    JPEGCOMPRESSION <ParameterNumber>
    ZLEVEL <ParameterNumber>
    PREDICTOR <ParameterNumber>
    TILED <ParameterBoolean>
    BIGTIFF <ParameterSelection>
    TFW <ParameterBoolean>
    EXTRA <ParameterString>
    OUTPUT <OutputRaster>
```

Note that it requires 16 parameters compared to your 10 :)

*Tested this on QGIS 2.14.1-Essen with Processing version 2.12.2*

Comment: I have made that correction, it runs - after execfile(..) it returns true because the isValid() - but keep saying "Algorithm not found", nevertheless, I open my toolbox and Reproject is available... I keep it activated in my plugin manager. According to the number of parameters, it doesn't complain now about number of them

Comment: @user64823 - Are you running your code inside QGIS (i.e. the Python console)? And are you getting an output?

Comment: I have written that code in the Text Editor of QGIS, sorry I forgot to tell so. Then, I run it and output is: True, Error: Algorithm not found

Layer is loaded to the interface.

Comment: Sorry so much, I have correct one parameter and it works (I have to input all the parameters correctly) because it now, exists. 

Thank you...

Comment: I have already : processing.runalg("gdalogr:warpreproject", rasterLyr, "EPSG:25830", "EPSG:3722", -9999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, False, 0, False, "Yes", "C:\...\MYREPROJECT.ecw")


And it returns :Wrong parameter value: 0 ; I follow all the types of parameters....